# Stuck on formal proof, missing one step

Tags: first-order-logic, formal-proofs

I'm stuck on what to put for step 7. Thank you!

1. Horned(c) → (Elusive(c) ∧ Dangerous(c))
2. (Elusive(c) ∨ Mythical(c)) → Rare(c)
3. Mammal(c) → ¬Rare(c)

   4. Horned(c)

      5. Mammal(c)
      6. ¬Rare(c) (→ Elim 5, 3)
      7. ?
      8. ⊥ (Rule ?)

   9.¬Mammal(c) (¬Intro 5-8)

**Goal 10.** Horned(c) → ¬Mammal(c)

Comment: Are you supposed to fill the blanks in a given proof or are 4-8 your own work?

Comment: You're suppose to do the entire thing on your own but Idk how to fill the part I missed.

Comment: Since you've assumed Horned you can use Implication Elimination, then And Elimination to conclude Elusive. Then you can get Elusive v Mythical by Or Introduction, and then Implication Elimination will give you Rare. And then...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than just 1 more step, but you are almost there:

7. $Elusive(c) \land Dangerous(c) \: (\rightarrow Elim 1,4)$
8. $Elusive(c) \: (\land Elim \: 7)$
9. $Elusive(c) \lor Mythical(c) \: (\lor Intro \: 8)$
10. $Rare(c) \: (\rightarrow Elim \: 2,9)$
11. $\bot \: (\bot Intro \: 6, 10)$